# Produce dot chart in highchart

Tags: highcharts

as of now Highchart has a lot of solutions for data visualization but i know it capable of drawing any chart to visualize the data.

I'm looking for dot chart similar to what RaphaelJS has done. Hope the team can share how to draw chart like that soonest..

Thanks

Comment: Here is full list of supported charts by Highcharts: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions - dot chart in Raphael is simple bubble chart in Highcharts.

Comment: appreciate if you can shed light on the plotOption to produce like Raphael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example in Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/HVpSp/

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble'
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: -0.5,
        max: 2.5,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        categories: ['a','b','c']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [[0,13],[0,16],[0,3],[0,18],[0,6]]
    }, {
        data: [[1,13],[1,16],[1,3],[1,18],[1,6]]
    }, {
        data: [[2,13],[2,16],[2,3],[2,18],[2,6]]
    }]

});
```